# Unable to reuse the content within a for loop when the source file is closed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro to read inputs from a close excel file and use the same in a for loop. If I run the macro as it is, I find it working. However, the problem is the close file remains open until the `for loop` is finished. I wish to read the content from the close file all at once and then close the file and finally reuse them in the for loop. The bottom line is I do not want to keep the source file open while doing the for loop.

```
Sub ReadFromClosedFile()
    Dim sourceFile As Workbook, cel As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, itemcol As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set sourceFile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\vba automation\LIST.xlsx", True, True)
    Set itemcol = sourceFile.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & sourceFile.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    
    'sourceFile.Close False

    For Each cel In itemcol
        R = R + 1: ws.Cells(R, 1) = cel
    Next cel
    
    sourceFile.Close False
End Sub
```

How can I reuse the content within a for loop when the source file is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, put the range in an array like in the next code:

```
Sub ReadFromClosedFile()
    Dim sourceFile As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, arrCol, r As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set sourceFile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\vba automation\LIST.xlsx", True, True)
    arrCol = sourceFile.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & _
                        sourceFile.Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row).Value
    sourceFile.Close False

    For r = 1 To UBound(arrCol)
         ws.cells(r, 1).Value = arrCol(r, 1)
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot loop through a range in a closed file. You can either copy the range in an array (as shown in @FaneDuru's answer). Alternatively, you can build a formula like this:

```vb
Sub ReadFromClosedFile()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook
    Dim sSrcFilename As String
    Dim sFormulaPath As String
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    
    sSrcFilename = "C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\vba automation\LIST.xlsx"
    
    With Workbooks.Open(sSrcFilename, True, True)
        lLastRow = .Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        sFormulaPath = .Path & "\[" & .Name & "]"
        .Close False
    End With
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lLastRow)
        .Formula = "='" & sFormulaPath & "Sheet1'!A1"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Note:** If you have a cell in the source file that calculates the maximum row number (e.g. using `COUNTA` worksheet function) you don't need to open the source file at all: Simply read the maximum row with a formula using the same technique above.

Comment: What a great idea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @VBasic2008 You're welcome. If somehow one can work out `lLastRow` without opening the file, then using this formula pattern works better. Otherwise, if one has to open the file, then reading the range into an array (as in your answer or @FaneDuru) would be the more sensible strategy.

Comment: Note that there is a way using `ADODb` without opening the file which would require the data type in the column(s) to be the same and... I'm not too familiar with it, so I won't do it. But it's no big deal, so it's worth investigating. Also opening the file in an other instance of `Excel` could contribute to the 'not opening the file' part.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Yes. That's another option that will generate a recordset instead of an array (works in a similar way).

Answer (score 1):

### Using an Array to Avoid a Loop

- You can vastly improve efficiency by writing the values of the source column range to an array thus avoiding the loop.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReadFromClosedFile()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    ' Source
    Const srcPath As String = "C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\vba automation\LIST.xlsx"
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcFirst As String = "A1"
    ' Destination
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dstFirst As String = "A1"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Handle Source
    
    ' Open Source Workbook (You know the path is correct).
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open(srcPath, True, True)
    
    ' Define Source Column Range (You know there is data).
    Dim rng As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(srcName).Range(srcFirst)
        Set rng = .Offset(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row)
        Set rng = .Resize(rng.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Write values from Source Column Range to Data Array
    ' (You know that there will be at least two rows (cells) of data).
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rng.Value
    
    ' Close Source Workbook.
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    ' Handle Destination
    
    ' Write values from Data Array to Destination Column Range.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dstName).Range(dstFirst)
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        .Resize(UBound(Data, 1)).Value = Data
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub ReadFromClosedFileSafer()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    ' Source
    Const srcPath As String = "C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\vba automation\LIST.xlsx"
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcFirst As String = "A1"
    ' Destination
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dstFirst As String = "A1"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Handle Source
    
    ' Attempt to open Source Workbook.
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open(srcPath, True, True)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Attempt to define Source Column Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(srcName).Range(srcFirst)
        Set rng = .Offset(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row)
        If rng.Row < .Row Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set rng = .Resize(rng.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Write values from Source Column Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        Data = rng.Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
    End If
    
    ' Close Source Workbook.
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    ' Handle Destination
    
    ' Write values from Data Array to Destination Column Range.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dstName).Range(dstFirst)
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        .Resize(UBound(Data, 1)).Value = Data
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```